# Configuration with name 'annotationProcessor' not found

Tags: gradle

I have this on my `build.gradle.kts` on the root of the project.

```
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        if (project.name != "processor") {
            annotationProcessor(project(":processor"))
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error when I try to build the code:

Configuration with name 'annotationProcessor' not found.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: it's probably due to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors etc. I'm investigating it ATM.